# How to prevent Nuxt 3 default layout from rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Because the [nuxt 3 docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/routing/layouts#layouts) are a `codesandbox` and do not explain anything, according to [nuxt 2 docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts/#default-layout) the `default layout` should be replaced by any layout that is specified inside the `name` property of `<nuxt-layout>` component but for me both layouts are rendered.

**`layouts/default.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>default layout</p>
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**`layouts/custom.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>custom layout</p>
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**`pages/index.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <nuxt-layout name="custom">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </nuxt-layout>
</template>
```

[image]

How do I only render the `custom` layout in `index.vue`?

**Edit:**

I understand that you can override the `default layout` by adding this to a component:

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "custom"
})
</script>
```

but this method assigns only one `layout`. How can I use the `html` version -> `<nuxt-layout name="custom"/>` without rendering the `default layout`? This way it would be possible to have multiple layouts in one component. In the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts) it shows that it should work, but for me it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pages, add this to your script. For more information visit [nuxt3-layouts](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts).

**~/pages/dashboard.vue**

```js
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "dashboard",
});
</script>
```

**~/pages/index.vue**

```js
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "default",
});
</script>
```

### Updated:

Disable the default layout from pages and instead use the built-in component `NuxtLayout` and add a name to it.
 Also don't forget to have an `app.vue` and `NuxtPage`. This will help in changing the layouts. Check [this](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#overriding-a-layout-on-a-per-page-basis) out.
**~pages/dashboard.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <NuxtLayout name="dashboard">
          <p style="color: red">This is dashboard</p>
      </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: false,
});
</script>
```

**app.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <NuxtLayout>
          <NuxtPage/>
      </NuxtLayout>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The downside of this method is that it gets applied to the whole component, instead of declaring `html` elements, who have specific children. The `doc` that you've linked sais that you can override the `default layout` just by adding `name` property to the `<nuxt-layout>` component but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your needs.

Comment: So you can't override `default layout` without having to manually add 3 lines of code into every component? That's not a great implementation. I guess I will just dump using a layout named `default`. Thanks anyway

Comment: As I tested, it's not possible to override the *default layout*. As you can see, if you wanted to override it, set the layout to false.

Comment: @Amini I don't understand why you add the layout tag two times. You should use only the layout tag in the pages not in app.vue . If you remove the layout tag from app.vue, and use it exclusively in pages, you don't need layout:false, and you can pick which layout use in each page without problems. Depending on how you design your layouts, you could in theory use more than one in your pages, and combine them to obtain your final design. If you use named layouts you could also avoid defining a default one. In app vue just keep the nuxtpage tag that's it.